# ESlint error "Cannot read property 'visitClass' of undefined" after update of packages

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, eslint

I did an npm update and started getting the following with eslint, the mystery is that babel-eslint and eslint versions were not updated.  How can I diagnose what the issue is.  Copying over the old node_modules folder gets it working again but it's hard for me to compare lib versions for every package.

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/Projects/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --format=checkstyle --stdin --stdin-filename test/email.js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'visitClass' of undefined
    at monkeypatch (/Users/jinteki/Projects/foo-web/node_modules/babel-eslint/index.js:199:40)
    at Object.exports.parse (/Users/jinteki/Projects/foo-web/node_modules/babel-eslint/index.js:410:5)
    at parse (/Users/jinteki/Projects/foo-web/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint.js:449:27)
    at EventEmitter.module.exports.api.verify (/Users/jinteki/Projects/foo-web/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint.js:603:15)
    at processText (/Users/jinteki/Projects/babycents-web/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:201:27)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnText (/Users/jinteki/Projects/foo-web/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:361:26)
    at Object.cli.execute (/Users/jinteki/Projects/foo-web/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli.js:179:36)
    at /Users/jinteki/Projects/foo-web/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js:13:28
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (/Users/jinteki/Projects/foo-web/node_modules/concat-stream/index.js:36:43)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
```

Comment: What versions of eslint and babel-eslint do you have? `npm ls eslint babel-eslint` This sounds like it could be [babel/babel-eslint#243](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/243).

Comment: ├── babel-eslint@3.1.30 
└── eslint@0.24.1

Comment: I just upgraded both babel-eslint and eslint to latest and it seems to work now, still not sure what the original issue was with the old versions but if it works I guess that's what matters ├── babel-eslint@6.1.2 
└── eslint@3.3.1